# Android ListView understanding

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a question about the ListView and how to use it. My Prolem is that my listView is only a part of the view and I am not sure how to do this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    String[] strings = new String[]{"Test1","Test2"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.ListView01,strings);
    myListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
```

I think the problem is the "this" in myArrayAdapter!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The layout resource id you're supposed to pass to ArrayAdapter is a layout that's used to render each item in the list, not the layout for the list itself.  Android provides some layout resources for the common cases.  Try using:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
```